# Proving an inequality between the difference of $\sqrt2$ and any rational number.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, rational-numbers

Let $a = \sqrt{2}$

Prove that for every $m,n\in N$

$|a - \frac{m}{n}| \gt \frac{1}{(2\sqrt2+1)n^2}$

Hint: Consider $|a - \frac{m}{n}|\geq 1$ and $|a - \frac{m}{n}|\leq 1$ as separate cases and consider the minimum of $|m^2 - 2n^2|$

Any and all help appreciated

Comment: Think about $|a-\frac mn|(a+\frac mn)$.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's theorem, $\left|\alpha-\frac{m}{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2n^2}$ implies that $\frac{m}{n}$ is a convergent of the continued fraction of $\alpha$.
If $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ these convergents are $\frac{1}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{5},\frac{17}{12},\frac{41}{29},\ldots$ or 
$$ \frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\left[(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n\right]}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[(1+\sqrt{2})^n-(1-\sqrt{2})^n\right]}, $$
since both $\{p_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $\{q_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ have the minimal polynomial $\lambda^2-2\lambda-1$. In explicit terms

$$ q_n^2\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\left|(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{2n}+2(-1)^n-(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{2n}\right| $$
equals
$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left|(1-\sqrt{2})^{2n}+(-1)^n\right|>\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}+1}. $$
It follows that no rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ are so good that $\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{m}{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{(2\sqrt{2}+1)n^2}$.
  The best we can do is to find approximations such that $\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{m}{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{(2\sqrt{2}-\varepsilon)n^2}$.